# Y-Axis not showing label while using multiple y-axes in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I need to display two y-axes for a linechart. I'm able to display the two axes, but I'm unable to show the labels for the second y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly mentioned the range for 2nd y axis. See if the below mentioned code is helpful

```
<mx:series>
    <mx:ColumnSeries id="cs1" dataProvider="{SMITH}" yField="close">
        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis id="v1" minimum="40" maximum="50"/>
        </mx:verticalAxis>
    </mx:ColumnSeries>
    <mx:LineSeries id="cs2" dataProvider="{DECKER}" yField="close">
        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis id="v2" minimum="150" maximum="170"/>
        </mx:verticalAxis>
    </mx:LineSeries>
</mx:series>
```

Comment: ya i have tried that also, still its not working for me, should we maintain separate data providers?

Comment: Issue has been fixed, the problem with using "gutterLeft" style.